# What's a better solr query for this system?

Tags: php, mysql, solr

I've hired a db consultant, who has been recommending the use of solr to handle the full text searching side of my current fully mysql system, in order to speed up the often slow searches (up to 30 secs per search).

The bulk of his/our has been spent a) tweaking the mysql settings to squeeze extra performance out, and b) installing solr. However, now we are near the end of our time, and the first few solr test queries seem to be falling over.

First, here's the relevant 3 tables of my current fully Mysql set up, plus the fully MySQL query that we're trying to replace with a MySQL/Solr approach. Then the Solr query we're testing.

**TABLE1** - a main table that full text searching records are stored in. They consist of a songID column, Artist column, and Title column. INDEXES - songID primary, Artist Fulltext (non unique), Artist btree (non unique), Title Fulltext (non unique), Title btree (non unique)

**TABLE2** - for storing DJ song lists. It references the above table's IDs. Some DJs have 150,000+ songs, and so have 150,000+ rows here that reference songs in TABLE1. TABLE2 also has an ID column, plus a song version column (named version) so DJs can apply their own version references to multiple versions of the same song (ie multiple rows for the same song, each with different version data). INDEXES - ID primary, djID btree (non unique), songID btree (non unique).

**TABLE3** - a tag map table, that contains references to the IDs in TABLE2, and IDs for tags (in another table called TAGS). It stores tags for each song in TABLE2 for genre, language, decade, plus DJs can have multiple song lists (tagged List1, List2 etc), so references to the song list each song belongs to. Potentially, each song can have up to about 12 tags per DJ. INDEXES - rowID primary, ID btree (non unique), tag_id (non unique)

Here's the current mysql search query for the artist keyword "beatles", and the only tag involved is one telling us to only select matches for songs in DJ 33's List1:

```
"SELECT t1.*, t2.version 
FROM  table1 t1, table2 t2, tagmap tm, tag t
WHERE MATCH (t1.Artist) AGAINST ('+beatles* ' IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
AND tm.tag_id = t.tag_id
AND (t.name IN ('List1'))
AND t2.ID = tm.ID
AND t2.songID = t1.songID
AND t2.djID = '33'
GROUP BY t2.ID
HAVING COUNT( tm.tag_id )=1
ORDER BY t1.Artist, t1.Title ASC LIMIT {$lastRowNum},{$limit1}";// pagination blah
```

It works, but on lists greater than 5000, it's slow.

**HIS PROPOSED SOLR SOLUTION:**

- make solr indexes for the songs in TABLE1
- during searches, query TABLE2 in mysql for the songIDs that belong to the DJ in question
- create a solr query for the keyword over Artist, and inject the DJ's songIDs into it...

  .../solr/select/?q=id:(3688804 3688807) AND Artist:beatles&wt=json

(I left the url out, and also the spaces and brackets so it's easy to view here, but they are replaced by %20 etc in the working code)

This above example with just 2 song IDs seemed to work, but on testing, the query fails as soon as you start to add roughly more than 1000 song IDs into it. Considering some DJs have 150,000 + songs, and therefore potentially 150,000+ unique songIDs to inject into the solr query, this seems a flawed solution.

Also, I have no idea how the tags will then come into the query process.

Thanks for taking a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend that you use Solr, but in a slightly different implementation.

All your DB normalization works great for transactional systems (i.e. adding songs, creating playlist etc.)

Search is something that works best on a de-normalized data structure. You could just create a Solr Schema that represents your search results and populate it using a SQL query.

The query is still in-efficient, but it need not run on every search (i.e. in real-time). Instead you could batch-populate the index nightly and trickle delta changes whenever songs/playlist etc change.

I wrote something on this [here](http://www.hacknlearn.in/2013/07/07/Handling-complex-data-structures/). Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Srikanth - I'm testing out a denormalised system this weekend.